# Have any academic superstars succeeded in a subject while disliking it?

Tags: career-path

This question is limited to only academic subjects that exist in internationally recognised universities (eg: exclude celebrities and Internet sensations), and is inspired by a discussion with a teenage family member who questions the maxim that interest is most important for deciding your academic subject: are there any academic luminaries who succeeded in a subject that they (secretely or not) despise?

For example, has any Nobel Laureate or [Rolf Schock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolf_Schock_Prizes#Laureates_in_Logic_and_Philosophy) winner despised the subject in which he/she won, or has any Fields Medallist despised maths?

Comment: I'm not sure how we could know.  If I met a Fields medalist who claimed to hate math, I wouldn't conclude that this was necessarily true.  Instead, I'd suspect that this person was a contrarian or loved being provocative.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no way to get a verifiable answer.

Comment: @vonbrand Presumably, famous researchers have been interviewed about the extent to which they enjoy working in their profession. Furthermore, famous researchers may have had private conversations about their attitude to  their research, and this information may be made public at a later date. So to my mind, it seems like an answerable question.

Comment: An interesting case - not in science, but cerebrally close enough, chess - is Emanuel Lasker: he considered Go to be superior to Chess despite being multi-year chess world champion.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, that doesn't mean he hates chess.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim, I've had bad days, when I was ready to throw it all out the window too. If you ask somebody who is already burnt out and retired, they'll presumably answer differently than when they were enthusiastic and active. Everybody hates one aspect or the other of their work, however much they love it overall.

Comment: @vonbrand Agreed. However, I try to approach the question in an as plausible way as possible. Note that you can be so good at your field that you are still excellent in a subfield which you detest but which you do very well, e.g. from a sense of duty (I know personal examples). It is, of course, unlikely that one will excel in a field that one overall detests from the very beginning. There will likely be a time when or other aspects where one will have liked it sufficiently for having had spent time on it. But that scope and time could have been quite limited and short-lived.

Comment: I've heard that Paul Cohen looked down on logic before resolving the Continuum Hypothesis, but this may be apocryphal.

Comment: I agree with @AnonymousMathematician (and I have voted to close).  To answer this question one would have to decide what it really means for someone to *dislike* something that they have worked intensely and protractedly on and had great success.  This is an interesting philosophical question -- e.g. how do we know that the sensations that we describe as "pleasure", "pain", "liking", "detesting"... are anything like the sensations that others use the same words to describe?  But this is not a question *about academia*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To succeed in any highly competitive endeavour requires long, concentrated, hard work. To put this into something you hate would certainly be a novel type of masochism, even if not successful.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a nice example, Einstein himself: he helped inventing/discovering Quantum Mechanics (by linking quantum hypothesis to photoelectric effect) but later fought against significant aspects of it (especially probabilistic outcomes, and incomplete state knowledgeability); nevertheless, he even later contributed the EPR paradoxon as a "counterexample" (but it became one of QM's foremost illustrations for nonlocality).

Comment: I guess this is more of an academic form of disliking. i.e., its not that Einstein disliked doing work in an area, it's that he questioned the academic merits of an approach or idea?

Comment: @JeromyAnglim I think it's probably as close as you can get with this question. He made several very negative and discouraged comments about the field. Amongst other: "Wenn es bei dieser verdammten Quantenspringerei bleiben soll, so bedaure ich, mich mit der Quantentheorie überhaupt befaßt zu haben" - have a translation at Google.

Comment: Einstein's field was *physics*; calling attention to (perceived) shortcomings of quantum mechanics is not at all an instance of saying that you dislike doing physics: in fact it *is* doing physics.  You seem to be interpreting the question by as asking whether a proponent of a certain academic theory later reversed herself and advocated against it: of course that happens quite frequently (in some fields and at some periods, more than half the time!).  I don't find this to be a plausible interpretation of the question.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I was tempted to agree, however: Quantum Mechanics was a very big chunk of physics at that time. How large does an area have to be for it to count? Since this is not very well defined (I know people who made their career in one field, but as soon as they could afford to they moved to another subfield in the major category and spoke not too flatteringly about their earlier field which built their career in the first place). Both fields belong into the same general category - but how large is an acceptable category? Science? Hate biology, love math? Hate algebra, love calculus?

Comment: @PeterL.Clark Sorry if my question were unclear; you are correct that I did not intend my question to include dislikes or retractions within a subject as in Einstein's case.